# Compute for the actual predicted values when labels or values are normalized

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, regression, conv-neural-network

I am building a pretrained CNN model for a regression problem, i.e. the predictions are continuous values instead of discrete labels.  For instance, predicting house pricing based on visual features.

Since the response values (y) are large, I would like to scale the data or as suggested by others, normalize from 0-1.  However, after scaling/normalization and training the model, the resulting predictions are in the scaled parameters. How can I compute for the actual values?  e.g. the actual house prices?

Comment: Based on what I've read, you may use standard or minmax scaler. But I have come across a source that applies np.log to the labels. I simply applied np.exp to revert the values. The results seem better! Thank you very much